# Floating image next to a div that aligns bottom

Tags: css-float, vertical-alignment

How can I float an image left of a div, and maintain that the div aligns bottom with the logo?

I swear I've done this before. I can't figure out how I did it though.

[See example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqwIY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Why float at all? Just using display: inline-block should inherently give you the behavior looking for. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/8sj12do1/

```css
.logo{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}

.link{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="link">Hi</div>
<div class="link">Hi</div>
<div class="link">Hi</div>
```

Comment: *FACEPALM* I knew I was over thinking this.Thank you!